# how to write some text into a file in different machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bash-functions

I have 2 machine machine1 and machine2.

I want to write from write some contents into file in machine2 from machine1.

In a same machine I can run `sudo cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to write the contents of `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

But I want to contents of `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` machine1 into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in machine2. I can do ssh and do this.
Since I'm installing hadoop in a silent mode in single command with username and password.

I don't want to do `scp` which replaces the whole file.

How can I do it in a single command supplying with username/password of another machine.

Comment: `ssh user@machine2 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`. But you don't need that. Use `ssh-copy-id` instead.

Comment: `sudo cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` There is no point using `sudo` there, you should avoid using sudo unless you actually need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh machine2 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

But you should probably use `ssh-copy-id` instead, which is a tool for that exact purpose:

```
ssh-copy-id machine2
```

or

```
ssh-copy-id id_dsa machine2
```

Comment: needless cat alert

Comment: Is this the cat police ? :)

Answer (score 4):

The ssh command captures local stdin and can also run external commands. If you combine these two facts then this becomes possible:

```
ssh machine2 tee -a "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

There is also a command called `ssh-copy-id` intended to automate this process. You can see `man ssh-copy-id` for more information.